# Start and stop command periodically, in Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, nat

I'm using [this](https://github.com/rofl0r/nat-tunnel) Python program to connect to a VPS and create a NAT tunnel.

```
My Home Windows PC <-- My Linux VPS <-- The internet
```

So now, even if my PC is behind a NAT, one can access the publicly exposed VPS and it will re-reoute the request to the Python script which will then re-reoute it to my home PC.

To launch the Python script on my home PC I use this simple batch file:

```
cd "%~dp0"
python.exe natsrv.py --mode client --secret hunter1 --local 127.0.0.1:8080 --admin myvps.ip.here:8999
```

This starts-up the Python script which never stops: it goes on indefinitely until I close the batch window. Very good.

Here's the problem: if the tunnel is unused for a few minutes, it silently stops serving requests. This won't stop the execution of the Python script, which will keep on going... it just stops working, but stays on.

I could fix this in the Python script but it's quite complicated and I don't want to mess with it: I want a much simpler solution.

**The batch file should stop the execution of python.exe and start it again, every 5 minutes**. How can I do this?

The SLEEP and GOTO commands or anything similar that I've tried, will wait before the Python script ends before being triggered!

I need to tell the batch script (or any entity controlling it) that python.exe must be stopped and restarted every 5 minutes, regardless of wether it's still running. Is it possible?

Comment: Use the `START` command to Launch the python script.  Then you can use `GOTO` and `TIMEOUT` and `TASKKILL` to loop back and restart it.

Comment: Your other Option would be to launch the python with Task Scheduler.  It can also kill previous versions of a started task.

Comment: I like the Task Scheduler idea a lot (was not aware it existed: not a Win expert). Am also testing START/TIMEOUT, will let you know what I can work out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you keep it alive by periodically pinging the VPS or something on the net?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea if I were to edit the original Python script: the reason it doesn't work is exactly what you specified, according to the brief research I did. It uses the Python "socket" library, and the solution to the problem is that one (pinging every n seconds). I'll probably dig into the original source and do it that way, once I can provide this quick and hacky fix of resetting the client.

Comment: You opened an issue - a fix is probable. - Hopefully a fix that entails periodically killing it then restarting won't kill it while being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a python script to run `natsrv.py` with the same command line arguments as a child process. Terminate it after 5 minutes and repeat.

*mynatsrv.py*

```
import subprocess as subp
import sys
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        p = subp.Popen(["python.exe", "natsrv.py"] + sys.argv[1:])
        time.sleep(5*60)
        p.terminate()
        p.wait()
```

and the command line is

```
cd "%~dp0"
python.exe mynatsrv.py --mode client --secret hunter1 --local 127.0.0.1:8080 --admin myvps.ip.here:8999
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I don't know how to launch a Py script, from another Py script, and pass command line arguments. I'd have to edit the original to work as a Py class/function, rather than a CLI script.

Comment: @Saturnix - so `natsrv.py` is not your program? I can change the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's a script I've found on Github. If it was mine I'd workout why it disconnects, but it uses APIs I don't know and dont' want to learn at the moment.

Comment: @Saturnix have you taken time to ensure that `natsrv.py` won't let somebody else through?

Comment: @wwii Nope: 0 security checks. If I can make it work, I'll run it in an isolated environment that I don't care if it gets infilatrated and for brief periods of time.